# Are completeness or properness preserved by mean curvature flows?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of $n$ dimensional with no boundary and $\varphi:M\times[0,T)\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be a smooth solution of the mean curvature flow
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial\varphi_t}{\partial t}=\Delta_t \varphi_t\ \ \ \text{ on }M\times[0,T). 
\end{align}
or a smooth family of immersions from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ moving by mean curvature.

Then are either of them true that:

> (i) the immersion $\varphi_t:M\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ remains to be
>   proper if the initial data $\varphi_0$ is proper.
>
> (ii) the metric $g_t$ on $M$ induced from the Euclidean metric of
>   $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by $\varphi_t$ remains to be complete if $g_0$ is
>   complete.

? Here a map $f:X\to Y$ between topological spaces $X, Y$ is said to be *proper* iff
\begin{align}
K\stackrel{\mathrm{compact}}\subset Y\Rightarrow f^{-1}(K)\stackrel{\text{compact}}\subset X. 
\end{align}

Hence if an immersion $\iota:M\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is proper, then it induces a complete metric on $M$. Thank you.